# How do I get rid of the 40% damage cap on elites?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In patch 1.03, a cap was added such that any attack done to elite enemies (e.g. lieutenants, mages, saarebas, and rage demons) is capped to 40% of their health.

So now however I spec my dual-wielding rogue, I never kill them in a single hit: my max tops out at 80% (40% per hand). The lacerate talent gets around this, but it only procs 10% of the time.

Since the rogue thrives on single target assassination and taking priority targets out of the fight immediately, I was hoping there was a way to remove this cap.

Answer (score 1):

[This mod](http://social.bioware.com/project/6654/) (which has no decent name) claims to remove the cap, but the mediafire link is broken and there are no files listed on the Bioware project page anymore, but according to [related comments](http://social.bioware.com/project/6654/#comments) it used to work.

Unfortunately that just tells us that *you could make your own mod to remove the cap.*

I do not know of any other way to get around the cap.

Comment: that mod doesn't seem to exist anymore, the link on the page goes to a dead link

Comment: @spartacus Oops, should have checked the mediafire link myself. Updated the answer to suit.

Comment: http://dragonage2.nexusmods.com/mods/3191/? this link may still be alive?

Comment: @ProbFixNask Sadly that appears to be the original haste/slow enemy patch that the author based his patch on, not the patch that includes both that and removing the 40% cap and fixing the invincible enemies bug.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fast Action Real Damage - Nightmare Mod](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=2519)  will significantly reduce enemy health. However your health is also reduced.

Comment: does this get around the 40% damage cap though?  I'd imagine your rogue would still be doing 40% of the damage of whatever you are attacking and still unable to 1 hit.